# A word for "waiting for a reply"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a system which has the following structure:

Inbound > Open > Pending > Awaiting reply > Ready > Closed

I'd like to use single-words, so the one that sticks out like a sore thumb is "Awaiting reply".

I obviously can't use "Pending" because that's already in use. And "Awaiting" is too similar to "Pending".

Is there a word for "waiting for a reply"?

Comment: Why do you need the reply? Does someone need to confirm something? What do they confirm? That it's done? complete? written?

Comment: As bizarre as it sounds, I'm being purposely vague to cover a multitude of possibile outcomes.

Comment: +1 Thanks for asking this. Came here today to ask the same question, for basically the same reason. (Too bad there isn't a silver-bullet answer.)

Comment: What is the reason for distinguishing between Pending and Awaiting Reply? Pending meaning you haven't yet taken action on your side, while Awaiting Reply means you need input from the other party to continue? I've seen "Impeded" used that way, but it has negative connotations I don't think you want here.

Answer (score 5):

How about "Unanswered"?

I know it's not the perfect answer -- it's not clear whether the items are unanswered by other people or unanswered by you. But then, the same could be said of "awaiting reply" :-)

Comment: Unanswered is good because it is a clear separation from Pending. Some good answers so far though.

Comment: You could also say: unreplied, it's also shorter :)

Comment: Except you couldn't use unreplied by itself, you would have to say "unreplied to" :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to live with "awaiting reply." Even if you do find a single word that comes close to the same meaning, it is likely to be obscure or not appropriate for the context.

In technical writing, which is how I would classify documenting a process, it is sometimes necessary to sacrifice elegance in favor of making your writing clear and easy to understand quickly with a minimum of mental friction. In this case, your goal is to make your writing "invisible": if the reader "notices" what you've written, that means you've failed. When the reader encounters the labels you've given the process steps, he or she should understand them immediately without a second thought. "Awaiting reply" achieves that goal, whereas a more flowery or clever single-word label may not.

Answer (score 1):

Rsvp(répondez, s'il vous plaît)-: used in formal invitations. (It is an abbreviation.) It is French  for "respond if you please".

Comment: Not sure if it is really used in real world but it is used formal invitation "format"(the one I learnt in school)

Comment: This seems to be describing the wrong part of the process. The other words are all statuses for something, whereas *RSVP* is a request/command made to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a single word for *waiting for a reply*. One can expect, anticipate, await, envisage, assume, etc, but they all would need *for a reply*.

One can be [expectant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/expectant) or expecting, but be aware that this word is commonly used for pregnant. One can also be *anticipant*, *anticipative*, *ready*, and *hopeful*, but I'm unsure these will meet your needs.

Expectant has a noble lineage.

> - There was about an average of two dogs to one man; and these sat in **expectant** attitudes till a spent bone was flung to them, and then they went for it by brigades and divisions, with a rush... - Mark Twain
> - ...and the crystal waters of the brooks, murmuring over the grey and white pebbles, hastened to pay their tribute to the **expectant** rivers... - Cervantes (Don Quixote)
> - He saw the yellow road, the lines of **expectant** people, and the sober houses. Crane (Red Badge of Courage)
> - the white birds were now all flying towards Ahab's boat; and when within a few yards began fluttering over the water there, wheeling round and round, with joyous, **expectant** cries. (Melville)

Answer (score 1):

How about "receiving"?
It suggests the expectation is still in the air. The act of receiving is not completed, hence: awaiting continues. 
Furthermore, "receiving" implies the "reply" part rather neatly. What can you "receive" if not a delivery of something (like mail, food, kisses, or just a... reply)?

Comment: If I correctly understand the intent of the question, I like this one: it indicates that the status is "ready to receive reply"

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could turn the focus around from the expected action of the respondent, to the last action of the maintainer/asker. For example, perhaps one of the following could be used:

- Inquired
- Requested
- Solicited
- Queried

At the moment I'm liking "queried", because it has two syllables, like everything else in the OP's list up until "closed".

Other synonyms for "request information" at [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/request%20information).

Answer (score 0):

"Holding" is a possibility. Though, as @phenry explained, the intent of this word could be misunderstood by your readers since it is somewhat ambiguous without further clarification of "holding for a reply."

From Merriam-Webster:

Holding:

a: to delay temporarily the handling of

"Please hold all my calls."

b :  to continue in the same way or to the same degree

"I hope the weather will hold." —often used with up

Here, holding would imply that you are maintaining a state of expectancy or holding off on any further action until a response is received.

Comment: You could improve your answer with a reference that backs up why you think it's a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a word that pertains to the anticipation felt when waiting for a response to a text message :
“TEXTPECTATION”

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]! If you made this up, you should state so; also, answers like that might be received badly by the community.